# Unwanted blank page

Tags: titles, emptypage

In my project, shown below, a blank page appears after the title and I don't want it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{paquetes}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{Apuntes de Radiactividad y Aplicaciones (3º Física)}
\author{Samuel G. Guerrero}
\date{Febrero 2020}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introducción}
\subfile{temas/Introduccion/Introduccion}

\end{document}
```

The preamble file `paquetes.sty` is the one below.

```
\ProvidesPackage{paquetes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\topmargin=-2cm
\oddsidemargin=-1cm
\evensidemargin=-1cm
\textwidth=17.5cm
\textheight=25cm
\footskip=20pt

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}} %cambiar "capitulo" por " tema%


\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{10pt}{}
```

Does anyone know why is this empty page appearing?

Fist page:

[image]

and second page (the one that I dont want):

[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `book` uses by default `twoside` and `openright`, which means chapters start on a right-hand page. Hence the blank page. Do you perhaps want `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`?

Comment: @egreg yes, that's what I wanted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'openany' option so that a new chapter can start on a left or right page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
```

https://texblog.org/2013/02/13/latex-documentclass-options-illustrated/#openright

Comment: That worked! Cheers!